# Public GIS data for lots within sections of township and range for NM, USA

Tags: shapefile, data, feature-class, united-states, plss

Anyone know where to find a publicly available shapefile/fc of lot divisions within sections for township and range of New Mexico?

I've been to several government websites that offer this type of data but can't seem to find any files that are broken down all of the way to the lot level.  I.E. land grids for section and twp/rng seem easy enough to come by from these sites where as lots are eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found one right after I posted this.

http://www.blm.gov/nm/st/en/prog/more/geographic_sciences/spatial_data_metadata.html

Followed the link for "Survey LandNet" which is a download for very detailed survey data.

Comment: As an FYI, http://www.geocommunicator.gov/geocomm/lsis_home/home/ is the root source for that data and contains some helpful documentation (such as the handbook pdf). The link you include is to the state specific division, and the data they post may be processed further or different than the original CadNSDI data. Some of the data sets on the individual state pages only go down to section, not lot level (though they derive from the same source).